# Biblatex: Two citation styles in the same document in two refsegments?

Tags: biblatex, biber, multiple-citations

Is it possible to have two citation styles in the same document separated by two refsegments? I'd like to have in the first segment a **numeric style**, as is in the MWE below, and in the second segment an **authoryear style**.

Here is a M(non-)WE.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest.bib}
@BOOK{BookA03,
    author    = {Author Aaa},
    title     = {Some Title},
    publisher = {Some Publisher},
    year      = 2003
}
@BOOK{BookB02,
     author    = {Author Bbb},
    title     = {Some Title},
    publisher = {Some Publisher},
    year      = 2002
}
    \end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatextest.bib}

\begin{document}
I want the citations to be in numeric in this segment as is.
\cite{BookA03,BookB02}
\printbibliography

\vspace{2cm}
\begin{refsegment}
Is there a way to change the citation style from numeric to authoryear in this new refsegment? 
\cite{BookA03,BookB02}
\end{refsegment}
\printbibliography[segment=2]   
\end{document}
```

The answers that I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602977/biblatex-multiple-citation-styles-in-the-same-document) and [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361826/customising-citation-style-changing-citation-style-locally) are not satisfactory. May be I missed a satisfactory answer?
Thanks for helping.